# How to gracefully handle promise rejection in express

Tags: express, promise, es6-promise, express-router

I have the following express controller

```
class ThingsController {

  static async index(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const things = await Thing.all();
      res.json(things);
    } catch(err) {
      next(err);
    }  
  }
}
```

and router

```
router.route('/things').get(ThingsController.index)
```

In my app I plan to have several controllers which use promises to render the result

I do not want to repeat try/catch block every time

My first solution was to extract this logic into handle promise rejection function:

```
const handlePromiseRejection = (handler) =>

  async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
      await handler(req, res, next);
    } catch(err) {
      next(err);
    };
  };
```

and now we can remove try/catch block from the ThingsController.index and need to change router to this:

```
router.route('/things')
  .get(handlePromiseRejection(ThingsController.index))
```

But adding `handlePromiseRejection` on every route might be tedious task and I would want to have more clever solution.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: check this out `express-async-errors` (somebody probably had the same thought as yours)

Comment: It worked like a charm @naga-elixir-jar. Could you please turn this comment into an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normal way of handling errors with `async/await` in routes is to catch the errors and pass it to the `catch all` error handler:

```
app.use(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await someAction();
  } catch (err) {
    // pass to error handler
    next(err)
  }
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // handle error here
  console.error(err);
});
```

With `express-async-errors` package, you could simply `throw` (or not worry about `error` thrown from some function). From docs: `Instead of patching all methods on an express Router, it wraps the Layer#handle property in one place, leaving all the rest of the express guts intact.`

Usage is simple:

```
require('express-async-errors'); // just require!
app.use(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findByToken(req.get('authorization')); // could possibly throw error, implicitly does catch and next(err) for you

  // throw some error and let it be implicitly handled !!
  if (!user) throw Error("access denied");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // handle error
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Actually it worked for me without the need to throwing an error manually. I have tests which check that app replies with 500 on promise rejection and they pass without the need to throw an error in a handler. Express has out of the box error handler which responds with 500 in case of an error

Comment: `if (!user) throw Error("access denied");` If you're refering to this line, author means you can throw error in your route instead of doing `next(error)`, the package implicitly does this for you. Just an example that you can throw error.

Answer (score 1):

So, that's how you handle promise rejection if you really want to handle on each route.

Here's a single liner ES6 version of it as well.

#### Code

```
const handlePromiseRejection = (handler) => (req, res, next) => handler(req, res, next).catch(next)
```

Though like you asked, the easiest way is to listen to the `unhandledRejection` on the process using on your index.js or app.js

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", (error, promise) => {
  console.log("Unhandled Rejection at:", promise, "reason:", reason);
  // Application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

From [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection)

Comment: The `handler(req, res, next).catch(next)` version of `handlePromiseRejection` won't work in case if the handler is not an async function (if we apply `handlePromiseRejection`on every route handler in the app)

Comment: True but the OP asked about handling Promise rejection with a universal approach.

Comment: the problem with your solution is that my browser hangs forever when I request an API endpoint and it fails with an unhandled promise rejection